# How to set registry value as batch variable

Tags: batch-file, outlook, registry

Trying to set values in the registry to variables which have been set in the batch script.

At the end of the day I just need the data for `NewSignature` under the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings`, to be the string returned by running `dir /b %appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures\*.txt`, so that the outlook profile signature that's already present is set to be used.

I've tried various ways of echoing the result or escaping the `%` values, but haven't found a way to return the actual value.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b %appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures\*.txt') do set sig=%%g

set si=%%sig:~0,4%%

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings" /v NewSignature /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %si% /f

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings" /v ReplySignature /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %si% /f
```

Currently it results in `%sig:~0,4%` being set as the registry value. The `~0,4` is to remove the `4` trailing characters from `*.txt` of the outlook signature profile. I need the actual value of `%sig:~0,4%` to be set as the registry value.
[value of registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPJnZ.png)

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly thank you. File NameWithoutExtension so that it will effectively use the profile signature name that is also the name of the file. I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this, but I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have replaced my comments with this answer.*

Firstly, with your provided code, you need to change `set si=%%sig:~0,4%%` to

```
set "si=%sig:~0,-4%"
```

However if you were only after the filename without extension, you don't need to `set` another variable and then expand it to remove the extension. You could simply remove:

```
set "si=%sig:~0,-4%"
```

and modify `for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b %appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures\*.txt') do set sig=%%g`

to read:

```
For %%A In ("%appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures\*.txt")Do Set "sig=%%~nA"
```

and use `%sig%` instead of `%si%` in your `reg add` lines:

```
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings" /V NewSignature /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D "%sig%" /F
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings" /V ReplySignature /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D "%sig%" /F
```

Additionally, you seem to be using a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` data type, when it shouldn't really be necessary, *as you're not using an expandable string, just a string*. You could therefore use this type of syntax:

```
Reg Add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings /V NewSignature /D "%sig%" /F
Reg Add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings /V ReplySignature /D "%sig%" /F
```

Putting it all together in a script it could look like this:

```bat
@Set "Fldr=%AppData%\Microsoft\Signatures"
@Set "RKey=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings"
@Set "Vals="NewSignature","ReplySignature""
@For %%A In ("%Fldr%\*.txt")Do @For %%B In (%Vals%)Do @Reg Add "%RKey%" /V %%B /D "%%~nA" /F>Nul
```

You could obviously still insert `/T REG_EXPAND_SZ` in the `Reg Add` command if you feel it necessary.

*Please note, that this entire answer assumes that there is only a single `.txt` file in the `Signatures` directory. If there can be more than one, you should try to explain how you'd like to choose the appropriate `.txt` file.*